# Как изменить цвет svg иконки?

Tags: html, css, svg

Что-то непонятное происходит с иконкой. Получается, что она состоит из элементов которые либо заливаются, либо обводятся.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Слой_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 21.1 20.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 21.1 20.1;" xml:space="preserve" width="240" height="240">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st1{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
 .st2{enable-background:new    ;}
 .st3{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);}
 .st4{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);mask:url(#SVGID_5_);}
 .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_7_);fill:#00D6D6;}
 .st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:none;stroke:#00D6D6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
 <defs>
  <rect id="SVGID_1_" width="21.1" height="20.1"/>
 </defs>
 <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
  <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"/>
 </clipPath>
 <g class="st0">
  <defs>
   <rect id="SVGID_3_" y="0" width="21.1" height="20.1"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
   <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" style="overflow:visible;"/>
  </clipPath>
  <defs>
   <filter id="Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="2.7" width="18.5" height="17.4">
    <feFlood style="flood-color:white;flood-opacity:1" result="back"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="back" mode="normal"/>
   </filter>
  </defs>
  <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="2.7" width="18.5" height="17.4" id="SVGID_5_">
   <g class="st1">
    <g class="st2">
     <rect x="11" y="-1.4" class="st3" width="11.7" height="11.7"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </mask>
  <g class="st4">
   <g>
    <defs>
     <rect id="SVGID_6_" y="2.7" width="18.5" height="17.4"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_7_">
     <use xlink:href="#SVGID_6_" style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <path class="st5" d="M12.7,20.1c-1.2,0-1.7-1.6-2.1-3.1c-0.3-1.1-0.7-2.6-1.3-2.6H9.2c-0.6,0-1,1.5-1.3,2.6      c-0.4,1.5-0.9,3.1-2.1,3.1c-2.1,0-3.8-3.7-4-4.2c-0.1-0.2-2.6-5.3-1.5-10C1.4,1.7,6.2,2.6,8.3,3c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.1,1,0.1h0.1      c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,1-0.1c2.1-0.4,6.9-1.3,7.9,2.9c1.2,4.6-1.4,9.8-1.5,10C16.5,16.3,14.8,20.1,12.7,20.1 M9.2,13.3L9.2,13.3      c1.5,0,2,1.7,2.4,3.4c0.2,0.9,0.6,2.3,1,2.3c1,0,2.3-2,3-3.5c0-0.1,2.5-5,1.4-9.2c-0.7-2.9-3.8-2.6-6.6-2.1      C9.9,4.2,9.5,4.3,9.3,4.3H9.2C8.9,4.3,8.6,4.2,8,4.1C5.2,3.6,2.1,3.3,1.4,6.2c-1.1,4.2,1.4,9.1,1.4,9.2c0.7,1.5,2,3.5,3,3.5      c0.4,0,0.8-1.4,1-2.3C7.3,15,7.8,13.3,9.2,13.3"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <polygon class="st6" points="20.6,3 18.1,3 18.1,0.5 16,0.5 16,3 13.5,3 13.5,5.2 16,5.2 16,7.7 18.1,7.7 18.1,5.2 20.6,5.2   "/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Так, цвет меняется в строках .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_7_);fill:#00D6D6;}
 .st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:none;stroke:#00D6D6;stroke-miterlimit:10;}, где задаете нужный 16-ричный цвет #rrggbb.

Answer (score 0):

```
.st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_7_);fill:#000;}
.st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
```

В этих двух строка #000 это черный я заменил ваш #00D6D6 можешь полностью вместе с # заменить на black или white какой нужен или же использую что то по типу https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp выбрать нужный цвет